# HTML5 File API - slicing or not?

Tags: html, file-upload, fileapi

There are some nice examples about file uploading at [HTML5 Rocks](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/) but there are something that isn't clear enough for me.

As far as i see, the example code about [file slicing](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/#toc-slicing-files) is getting a specific part from file then reading it. As the note says, this is helpful when we are dealing with large files.

The example about [monitoring uploads](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/#toc-monitoring-progress) also notes this is useful when we're uploading large files.

Am I safe without slicing the file? I meaning server-side problems, memory, etc. Chrome doesn't support `File.slice()` currently and i don't want to use a bloated jQuery plugin if possible.

Answer (score 6):

Both Chrome and FF support `File.slice()` but it has been prefixed as `File.webkitSlice()` `File.mozSlice()` when [its semantics changed](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/group/chromium-html5/browse_thread/thread/2c963f6ecdae0573?pli=1) some time ago. There's another example of using it [here](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2011/08/Seek-into-local-files-with-the-File-System-API) to read part of a .zip file. The new semantics are:

```
Blob.webkitSlice( 
  in long long start, 
  in long long end, 
  in DOMString contentType 
);
```

Are you safe without slicing it? Sure, but remember you're reading the file into memory. The HTML5Rocks tutorial offers chunking the upload as a potential performance improvement. With some decent server logic, you could also do things like recovering from a failed upload more easily. The user wouldn't have to re-try an entire 500MB file if it failed at 99% :)

Comment: And then there's Opera, implemented `.slice()` but in two different ways, one following the w3c and one that didn't =/

Comment: [MDN says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Blob) that, as of Firefox 13 and Chrome 21, `slice()` is no longer prefixed.

Comment: You can use the method without prefix in newer versions of most browsers.

Comment: Does HTml Slice loads the File in memory first and then Slices? Actually i looking into resumable.js and in case of large files its taking a lot of time in slicing,so wondering is this in client memory?

Answer (score 0):

This is the way to slice the file to pass as blobs:

```
function readBlob() {
    var files = document.getElementById('files').files;
    var file = files[0];
    var ONEMEGABYTE = 1048576;
    var start = 0;
    var stop = ONEMEGABYTE;

    var remainder = file.size % ONEMEGABYTE;
    var blkcount = Math.floor(file.size / ONEMEGABYTE);
    if (remainder != 0) blkcount = blkcount + 1;

    for (var i = 0; i < blkcount; i++) {

        var reader = new FileReader();
        if (i == (blkcount - 1) && remainder != 0) {
            stop = start + remainder;
        }
        if (i == blkcount) {
            stop = start;
        }

        //Slicing the file 
        var blob = file.webkitSlice(start, stop);
        reader.readAsBinaryString(blob);
        start = stop;
        stop = stop + ONEMEGABYTE;

    } //End of loop

} //End of readblob
```

Comment: `FileReader.readAsBinaryString()` is deprecated. It's no longer in the [W3C File API](https://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/#dfn-filereader) working draft:     `// async read methods`
    `void readAsArrayBuffer(Blob blob);`
    `void readAsText(Blob blob, optional DOMString label);`
    `void readAsDataURL(Blob blob);`