# How to store huge files in chrome with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-app, html5-filesystem

I need to store some large binary files varying from about 5MB to about 1GB and random access them in my Google Chrome App.

But `FileReader` doesn't provide `seek` method so maybe I have to split a file into segments. Is there any other way to access large files without loading the whole file into memory?

And where should I store these files or segments? If there are many segments, will it cause performance problems?

1. fileSystem
2. localStorage
3. indexDB
4. webSQL

Comment: localStorage isn't a bad idea since it's capacity is of *[at least 5MB](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)*, but I think it'll not support a 1GB file.

Comment: Neither IndexDB nor WebSQL will be good options for binary data. Store the files in a FileSystem. The File object inherits from Blob which has a `slice()` method, so it should be possible to do some sort of random access with that. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7594760/html5-file-api-slicing-or-not) might give you some pointers